# split a line into many part base on curly brace ?

Tags: shell-script, split

I have a 1-line file which has a format of:

```
{port1 dev1 M1 s} {port1 dev1 M1 s} {port3 dev2 M1 g} {port1 dev1 M1 d} {port1 dev1 M3 g} ...
```

I want to split this line and cat to output file base on the curly brace { } like this. How do I do that ?

```
port1 dev1 M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s 
port3 dev2 M1 g 
port1 dev1 M1 d 
port1 dev1 M3 g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With perl:

```
perl -lne 'print for /{(.*?)}/g' file
port1 dev1 M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s
port3 dev2 M1 g
port1 dev1 M1 d
port1 dev1 M3 g
```

Or using sed:

```
sed 's/{\([^}]*\)} */\1\n/; P;D' file
port1 dev1 M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s
port3 dev2 M1 g
port1 dev1 M1 d
port1 dev1 M3 g
...
```

Comment: you can simplify the sed command quite a bit by just using the `g` at the end of the regex and doing away with the loop all together, i.e. `sed 's/{\([^}]*\)} */\1\n/g' file`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` built with PCRE  support:

```
grep -Po '{\K[^}]*'
```

Or for the sequences of non-{} including at least a non-space:

```
grep -o '[^{}]*[^{}[:space:]][^{}]*'
```

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -o1 '{(.*?)}'
```

If `{...}`s may be nested (but balanced):

```
pcregrep -o1 '{((?:[^{}]+|(?0))*)}'
```

On an input like:

```
{port1 {dev1 dev2} M1 s} {port1 dev1 M1 s}
```

It gives:

```
port1 {dev1 dev2} M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr '}' '\n' <file | sed -E 's/^ ?\{//'
port1 dev1 M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s
port3 dev2 M1 g
port1 dev1 M1 d
port1 dev1 M3 g
```

This first replaces each `}` with a newline using `tr`. This gives the `sed` command individual lines to work with, where each line will start with a possible space and a `{`.  These characters are removed from the start of the line by the `sed` command.

The same thing with just `sed`:

```
sed -E -e 's/ ?\{//g' -e 'y/}/\n/'
```

The `y` command works like `tr` in this example.

---

Using GNU `awk` or `mawk`, but not BSD `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='[{}]' '/[^[:blank:]]/' file
port1 dev1 M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s
port3 dev2 M1 g
port1 dev1 M1 d
port1 dev1 M3 g
```

This interprets the data as records separated by either `{` or `}`, and then prints each such record that contains something other than just tabs or spaces.

---

Using Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'map { print "$_\n" } /{(.*?)}/g' file
port1 dev1 M1 s
port1 dev1 M1 s
port3 dev2 M1 g
port1 dev1 M1 d
port1 dev1 M3 g
```

This applies a `print` command to each element returned by matching the given regular expression against the input.  The `print` command also appends a newline to each element to get them on individual lines.

Comment: your `awk` produces two empty lines at the end. and `tr+sed`/`sed` single empty line.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with GNU sed:

```
sed -e 's/} {/\n/g' -e 's/^{//' -e 's/}//' input-file > output-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `sed` + `tr`.

```
sed -e '1,$s/}\s/#/g' input-file | tr '#' '\n' | tr -d '{|}' > output-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **grep + tr:**

```
grep -o  "{[^}]*" file | tr -d '{'
```

Using **sed:**

```
sed -e 's/{\(.*\)}/\1/' -e 's/} {/\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using "sed" as shown:

```
sed -ne 'y/{}/\n\n/;/^\s/D;/./P;D' input.file
```

where the P;D combo sets up an implicit loop and during the body of the loop we make sure to print non-empty fields.

Along similar lines:

```
perl -lne 'print for grep /\H/, split /{|}/' input.file
```

where we split the record, then filter the nonempty fields and print them one/line in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

With bash

```
var=$(<infile)
var="${var//\} {/$'\n'}"
echo "${var//[{\}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tr`:

```
<infile tr -s '}{' '\n '
 port1 dev1 M1 s
 port1 dev1 M1 s
 port3 dev2 M1 g
 port1 dev1 M1 d
 port1 dev1 M3 g
```